# Dynamic content in text field in JRXML file

Tags: jasper-reports

Below is the code snippet

```xml
<staticText>
  <reportElement key="staticText-2" mode="Opaque" x="381" y="242" width="79" height="18" forecolor="#000000" backcolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="4ec23e25-c8d9-4941-bd81-777aff6c08a7">
  <reportElement/>

  <text><![CDATA[14.01.2019]]></text>
</staticText>
```

Each month we need to change the date in JRXML file manually `<text><![CDATA[14.01.2019]]></text>` as 14.11,14,12 etc.

How can I automate this feature? Like code will read the current system date, once it reaches 14th of the month , automatically the date will change in jrxml file as well?

Please help.

Comment: Where is code snippet?

Comment: @PallaviG It's important to [format](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) your code (indent 4 spaces), because xml becomes invisible otherwise

Answer (score 0):

You could turn the `staticText` into a `textField` where you could use an expression based on JasperReports built-in date/time functions, like so:

```
<textField>
    <reportElement key="staticText-2" mode="Opaque" x="381" y="242" width="79" height="18" forecolor="#000000" backcolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="4ec23e25-c8d9-4941-bd81-777aff6c08a7"/>
    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[DATEFORMAT(EDATE($P{AccountingDate}, 1), "14.MM.yyyy")]]></textFieldExpression>
</textField>
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you so much for the answer. But when i tried to execute this code its showing the date as "14/12/2018". But i want to show next month date. Like current month is Jan , so i should display 14.02.2019. Requirement is: From Jan 1 to Jan 30 the date should display as Feb 14 (14.02.2019), And for Feb1 to Feb 28  the date should display as 14.03.2019. Its like for the current month we should display next month 14.mm.yyyy as the date.

Comment: Hi Again, Requirement got changed from client side. I need to use the "accounting date " field in the report (which is nothing but the current date). And that parameter is declared as follows: <parameter name="AccountingDate" class="java.sql.Timestamp" isForPrompting="false">
  <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[bdw.reportmanager.HPDFormatter.getTimestamp("2006", "1", "31")]]></defaultValueExpression>
 </parameter>   So how can i make use this "Accounting date" and display next month date? NOTE: accounting date is nothing but the current date. IT would be great if u can please help. Thank you

Comment: H Narcis, The code which you given is showing current month date only like now it is january. Its showing 14.01.2019. But i want to display it as 14.02.2019. Can you please help?

Comment: You must not have the correct date to work on. Try switching `$P{AccountingDate}` with `TODAY()` and see what happens. This assumes that the system date/time is configured correctly.

Comment: Hi, Accounting date is 12.10.2018 , So according to that it should display as 14.11.2018 as due date. I tried but it gave me error while compiling. :( basically i should take accounting date only and display the due date as next month 14... kindly help.

Comment: What is the output for a textfield with this expression: `DATEFORMAT($P{AccountingDate}, "dd.MM.yyyy")`?

Comment: test env Accounting date is :29.10.18 
for code:
<textFieldExpression><![CDATA[DATEFORMAT(EDATE($P{AccountingDate}, 1), "14.MM.yyyy")]]></textFieldExpression>
 Result: 14.10.2018  // it should display as 14.11.2018 
for code:
<textFieldExpression><![CDATA[DATEFORMAT($P{AccountingDate}, "dd.MM.yyyy")]]></textFieldExpression>   
Result: 30.09.2018 

We dont run EOD daily in test env. So the accounting date is old. But in prod EOD will run daily.
Based on the "accounting date" whatever the env i should display next month (14.mm.yyyy).
Please help.

Comment: From the code I've asked you to run, it looks like your accounting date is 30.09.2018. So you are getting the appropriate results. The `EDATE()` function is implemented [here](https://github.com/TIBCOSoftware/jasperreports/blob/jr-6-6-0/jasperreports/demo/samples/functions/src/net/sf/jasperreports/functions/standard/DateTimeFunctions.java#L265-L284) if you need to take a look. There's nothing more I can do. You should work with a known date, display it along with the formatted one and then switch to the date coming from the parameter. There should not be more than this.